# Meteor: subscribe is not working

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to build a very simple **Meteor app**. I have implemented all CRUD. But my problem is when I have use **publish** and then **subscribe**, no data is returned. My code is given below:

**imports\api\tasks\tasks.js**

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

TasksSchema = new SimpleSchema({
   title: {
    type: String
   },
   owner: {
     type: String
   }
 });

export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks', { schema: TasksSchema });

if (Meteor.isServer) {
   Meteor.publish('task.list', function() {
       return Tasks.find({ owner: this.userId });
   });
}
```

**imports\ui\components\home\home.js**

```
import { Tasks } from '/imports/api/tasks/tasks.js';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating'
import { ReactiveDict } from 'meteor/reactive-dict';

import './home.html';

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.home.onCreated(function bodyOnCreated() {
       Meteor.subscribe('task.list');
    });

    Template.home.helpers({
        tasks() {
            let userId = Meteor.userId();
            return Tasks.find({ owner: userId }, { sort: { updatedAt: -1 } });
        }
   });
}
```

**imports\ui\components\home\home.html**

```
 <!-- here nothing is shown,although I have data -->
 {{#each task in tasks  }}

      {{task.title}} 

  {{/each}}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `{{task.title}} ` try `{{title}}` and also check in browser console `Task.find({}).fetch()` and see whether you can see records or not

Comment: It works @Sasikanth, Thank you

Comment: I posted it as an answer you can accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `{{task.title}}` try `{{title}}` and also check in browser console Task.find({}).fetch() and see whether you can see records or not.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because your subscription isn't ready to be used on client.
What you have to do is wrap your `each` code in `subscriptionsReady` function like below:

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}    
  {{#each task in tasks  }}
    {{task.title}} 
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
  <p>Loading...</p>
{{/if}}
```

Above should work.
You can check [this](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/subscriptions-and-data-management/with-blaze) link for more information of how to use `subscriptionsReady`